# Place an element everywhere inside a section to best fit vertical space

Tags: floats, sectioning, positioning, verse

I have a list of poems (but it could be anything else) containing sometimes some big complex poems (witch called [calligrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calligram) ) who have to never be breaked.

So, the document have multiple sections. Then, if I place a calligram inside a section, it could take place at any position inside this section, — but he should never go outside this section —.

The goal is to avoid big blank space at the end of a page before the calligram.

So this is my MWE :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{article}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@vstypeptitle}[1]{%
  \vspace{\beforepoemtitleskip}
  {\poemtitlefont #1\par\nobreak}\nobreak
  \vspace{\afterpoemtitleskip}\nobreak
}
\makeatother




\begin{document}

\section*{First section}
\poemtitle{A Fairy Song }
\begin{verse}
Over hill, over dale,\\
Thorough bush, thorough brier,\\
Over park, over pale,\\
Thorough flood, thorough fire!\\
I do wander everywhere,\\
Swifter than the moon's sphere;\\
And I serve the Fairy Queen,\\
To dew her orbs upon the green;\\
The cowslips tall her pensioners be;\\
In their gold coats spots you see;\\
Those be rubies, fairy favours;\\
In those freckles live their savours;\\
I must go seek some dewdrops here,\\
And hang a pearl in every cowslip's ear. 
\end{verse}


\poemtitle{Message de la ville}%
{\tiny%
\setstackTAB{ }%
\fixTABwidth{T}%
\tabbedCenterstack{
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ D ~ ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u n s ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ é u l ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ é l a ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n v e ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ r s l ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e s n ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u a g ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e s t ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e n d ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u e d ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e s e ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s q u ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ a r a ~ ~ ~\\
~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n t e ~ ~ ~\\
v i l l e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ t o u r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ é t a ~ ~ ~\\
h a u t e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s l a n ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ g e s ~ ~ ~\\
p o è m e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ c é e s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ l a v ~ ~ ~\\
a u t r e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ à l a s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i l l ~ ~ ~\\
t o u r s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ V V V V ~ ~ s a u t ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e p a ~ ~ ~\\
t o i t s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i i i i ~ ~ d e c e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ r d e ~ ~ ~\\
b é t o n ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ l l l l ~ ~ j o u r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s s u ~ ~ ~\\
m o n t e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ l l l l ~ ~ c o m m ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s l e ~ ~ ~\\
f r o i d ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ A t t ~ ~ e e e e ~ ~ e l e s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s t o ~ ~ ~\\
g l a c e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e n t ~ ~ a r r à ~ ~ l e t r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i t s ~ ~ ~\\
m i n c e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i o n ~ ~ u i e e ~ ~ r e s s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n o u ~ ~ ~\\
v i t r e ~ ~ S i v o u s ~ ~ x r g x ~ ~ u r l a ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s d é ~ ~ ~\\
l i s s e ~ ~ p r e n e z ~ ~ m e a p ~ ~ p a g e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s i g ~ ~ ~\\
j a i m e ~ ~ l a s c e n ~ ~ i v r l ~ ~ l e c i ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n e l ~ ~ ~\\
l a r u e ~ ~ s e u r a v ~ ~ l i d o ~ ~ e l p r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e c i ~ ~ ~\\
a u t o s ~ ~ e c l e s p ~ ~ l l v r ~ ~ i s o n ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e l d ~ ~ ~\\
m o t o s ~ ~ r i t f a r ~ ~ e l i e ~ ~ n i e r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u d o ~ ~ ~\\
v é l o s ~ ~ c e u r i l ~ ~ f e l r ~ ~ d e s v ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i g t ~ ~ ~\\
f o u l e ~ ~ a p p u i e ~ ~ e s l m ~ ~ i t r a ~ ~ ~ V a g u e s d ~\\
l a s s e ~ ~ r a s u r u ~ ~ n a e o ~ ~ g e s b ~ ~ e l a f o u l e c\\
t o u t e ~ ~ n b o u t o ~ ~ è n p t ~ ~ r i s e ~ ~ o m m e b a t l a\\
p l a c e ~ ~ n q u i v o ~ ~ t g o à ~ ~ l e s o ~ ~ h o u l e c o n t\\
r o u l e ~ ~ u s e n v e ~ ~ r l è m ~ ~ l e i l ~ ~ r e l a j e t é e\\
l e n t e ~ ~ r r a s u r ~ ~ e o m o ~ ~ a l e n ~ ~ s a n s j a m a i\\
h o u l e ~ ~ P l u t o n ~ ~ s t e t ~ ~ t o u r ~ ~ s s a r r e t e r\\
p a s s e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~\\
e t m o i l e s n é o n s m e c l i g n e n t d e l o e i l l e s m o t\\
s s o n t e n v i t r i n e p o u r d é c h i f f r e r l a v i l l e t\\
o u t e s l e s i m a g e s s a n i m e n t e t v o i l a q u e j e p r\\
e n d s p a r l a m a i n l a p o é s i e q u i c o u r t l e s r u e s
}
}

\poemtitle{Bar}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second section}

\poemtitle{Baz}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

As you see, *Message de la ville* should be in the first section. No mater if he come before *A fairy song* or after *bar*. It just have to be place before the Second section title. But unfortunately, in the output, it give a big blank space in the first page.

[image: First page of the output]

(Do not worry about the quality, it’s just the imagemagick convertion who break it)

But their is enough content appearing after *Message de la ville* who should ideally come before it.

[image: Second page of the output]

So, I just whant to tell LaTeX theire is a subsection who shoud comme before another subsection and after another subsection, inside a section.

I tried to put the whole calligram and title inside a `figure` environement, but then, the calligram could come *inside* another poem, he didn’t let it finish

So, how to let LaTeX automatically chose the best position of a poem inside his specified section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To meet all your goals (minimum blank space in pages, keep calligrams in one piece, have everything inside their section), you have to help LaTeX a little. And it might require following a filling strategy.

Both "Message de la ville" and "A Fairy Song" do not fit on the same page after the section title.

One strategy is to place the largest item first, then accommodate the next one that fits, and so on, until the page is full. So "Message de la ville" should go first (page #3).

The second candidate, "A Fairy Song", is too long to fit completely in the remaining space on the first page. To keep it together I used a new `newpoem` environment with a float inside, using the `newfloat` package, so it will go on top of the second page, while the remaining space on the first page is taken up by "Bar" and the following text (pages #3 and #4).

The alternative, that has "A Fairy Song" after the first section title and complete the first page with "Bar" and text, will not fill the page completely  --at least in this particular example-- (page #1).

It is now "Message de la ville" in the `newpoem` environment and will appear, in one piece, on the next page, but before the title of the second section (page #2}.

[image: b]

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,french]{article}

\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}

%*****************************************  *% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{newfloat} 
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{floatpoem}

\newenvironment{newpoem}[1]
{\begin{floatpoem}[!ht]
        \poemtitle{#1}
        \begin{verse}
                }
{\end{verse}\end{floatpoem}}
%*********************************************************

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@vstypeptitle}[1]{%
    \vspace{\beforepoemtitleskip}
    {\poemtitlefont #1\par\nobreak}\nobreak
    \vspace{\afterpoemtitleskip}\nobreak
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}    

    \section{First section}
    
    \poemtitle{A Fairy Song } 
    \begin{verse}
        Over hill, over dale,\\
        Thorough bush, thorough brier,\\
        Over park, over pale,\\
        Thorough flood, thorough fire!\\
        I do wander everywhere,\\
        Swifter than the moon's sphere;\\
        And I serve the Fairy Queen,\\
        To dew her orbs upon the green;\\
        The cowslips tall her pensioners be;\\
        In their gold coats spots you see;\\
        Those be rubies, fairy favours;\\
        In those freckles live their savours;\\
        I must go seek some dewdrops here,\\
        And hang a pearl in every cowslip's ear. 
    \end{verse}
    
    
    \begin{newpoem}{Message de la ville}    % floating Message de la ville
    {\tiny%
        \setstackTAB{ }%
        \fixTABwidth{T}%
        \tabbedCenterstack{%
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ D ~ ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u n s ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ é u l ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ é l a ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n v e ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ r s l ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e s n ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u a g ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e s t ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e n d ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u e d ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e s e ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s q u ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ a r a ~ ~ ~\\
            ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n t e ~ ~ ~\\
            v i l l e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ t o u r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ é t a ~ ~ ~\\
            h a u t e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s l a n ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ g e s ~ ~ ~\\
            p o è m e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ c é e s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ l a v ~ ~ ~\\
            a u t r e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ à l a s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i l l ~ ~ ~\\
            t o u r s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ V V V V ~ ~ s a u t ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e p a ~ ~ ~\\
            t o i t s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i i i i ~ ~ d e c e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ r d e ~ ~ ~\\
            b é t o n ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ l l l l ~ ~ j o u r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s s u ~ ~ ~\\
            m o n t e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ l l l l ~ ~ c o m m ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s l e ~ ~ ~\\
            f r o i d ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ A t t ~ ~ e e e e ~ ~ e l e s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s t o ~ ~ ~\\
            g l a c e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e n t ~ ~ a r r à ~ ~ l e t r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i t s ~ ~ ~\\
            m i n c e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i o n ~ ~ u i e e ~ ~ r e s s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n o u ~ ~ ~\\
            v i t r e ~ ~ S i v o u s ~ ~ x r g x ~ ~ u r l a ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s d é ~ ~ ~\\
            l i s s e ~ ~ p r e n e z ~ ~ m e a p ~ ~ p a g e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s i g ~ ~ ~\\
            j a i m e ~ ~ l a s c e n ~ ~ i v r l ~ ~ l e c i ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n e l ~ ~ ~\\
            l a r u e ~ ~ s e u r a v ~ ~ l i d o ~ ~ e l p r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e c i ~ ~ ~\\
            a u t o s ~ ~ e c l e s p ~ ~ l l v r ~ ~ i s o n ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e l d ~ ~ ~\\
            m o t o s ~ ~ r i t f a r ~ ~ e l i e ~ ~ n i e r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u d o ~ ~ ~\\
            v é l o s ~ ~ c e u r i l ~ ~ f e l r ~ ~ d e s v ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i g t ~ ~ ~\\
            f o u l e ~ ~ a p p u i e ~ ~ e s l m ~ ~ i t r a ~ ~ ~ V a g u e s d ~\\
            l a s s e ~ ~ r a s u r u ~ ~ n a e o ~ ~ g e s b ~ ~ e l a f o u l e c\\
            t o u t e ~ ~ n b o u t o ~ ~ è n p t ~ ~ r i s e ~ ~ o m m e b a t l a\\
            p l a c e ~ ~ n q u i v o ~ ~ t g o à ~ ~ l e s o ~ ~ h o u l e c o n t\\
            r o u l e ~ ~ u s e n v e ~ ~ r l è m ~ ~ l e i l ~ ~ r e l a j e t é e\\
            l e n t e ~ ~ r r a s u r ~ ~ e o m o ~ ~ a l e n ~ ~ s a n s j a m a i\\
            h o u l e ~ ~ P l u t o n ~ ~ s t e t ~ ~ t o u r ~ ~ s s a r r e t e r\\
            p a s s e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~\\
            e t m o i l e s n é o n s m e c l i g n e n t d e l o e i l l e s m o t\\
            s s o n t e n v i t r i n e p o u r d é c h i f f r e r l a v i l l e t\\
            o u t e s l e s i m a g e s s a n i m e n t e t v o i l a q u e j e p r\\
            e n d s p a r l a m a i n l a p o é s i e q u i c o u r t l e s r u e s
        }
    }
\end{newpoem}

\poemtitle{Bar}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Second section}

\poemtitle{Baz}
\lipsum[2]

\clearpage

\section{Third section}

\poemtitle{Message de la ville}%
{\tiny%
    \setstackTAB{ }%
    \fixTABwidth{T}%
    \tabbedCenterstack{
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ D ~ ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u n s ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ é u l ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ é l a ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n v e ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ r s l ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e s n ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u a g ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e s t ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e n d ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u e d ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e s e ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s q u ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ a r a ~ ~ ~\\
        ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n t e ~ ~ ~\\
        v i l l e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ t o u r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ é t a ~ ~ ~\\
        h a u t e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s l a n ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ g e s ~ ~ ~\\
        p o è m e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ c é e s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ l a v ~ ~ ~\\
        a u t r e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ à l a s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i l l ~ ~ ~\\
        t o u r s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ V V V V ~ ~ s a u t ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e p a ~ ~ ~\\
        t o i t s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i i i i ~ ~ d e c e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ r d e ~ ~ ~\\
        b é t o n ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ l l l l ~ ~ j o u r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s s u ~ ~ ~\\
        m o n t e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ l l l l ~ ~ c o m m ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s l e ~ ~ ~\\
        f r o i d ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ A t t ~ ~ e e e e ~ ~ e l e s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s t o ~ ~ ~\\
        g l a c e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e n t ~ ~ a r r à ~ ~ l e t r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i t s ~ ~ ~\\
        m i n c e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i o n ~ ~ u i e e ~ ~ r e s s ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n o u ~ ~ ~\\
        v i t r e ~ ~ S i v o u s ~ ~ x r g x ~ ~ u r l a ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s d é ~ ~ ~\\
        l i s s e ~ ~ p r e n e z ~ ~ m e a p ~ ~ p a g e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ s i g ~ ~ ~\\
        j a i m e ~ ~ l a s c e n ~ ~ i v r l ~ ~ l e c i ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ n e l ~ ~ ~\\
        l a r u e ~ ~ s e u r a v ~ ~ l i d o ~ ~ e l p r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e c i ~ ~ ~\\
        a u t o s ~ ~ e c l e s p ~ ~ l l v r ~ ~ i s o n ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ e l d ~ ~ ~\\
        m o t o s ~ ~ r i t f a r ~ ~ e l i e ~ ~ n i e r ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ u d o ~ ~ ~\\
        v é l o s ~ ~ c e u r i l ~ ~ f e l r ~ ~ d e s v ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ i g t ~ ~ ~\\
        f o u l e ~ ~ a p p u i e ~ ~ e s l m ~ ~ i t r a ~ ~ ~ V a g u e s d ~\\
        l a s s e ~ ~ r a s u r u ~ ~ n a e o ~ ~ g e s b ~ ~ e l a f o u l e c\\
        t o u t e ~ ~ n b o u t o ~ ~ è n p t ~ ~ r i s e ~ ~ o m m e b a t l a\\
        p l a c e ~ ~ n q u i v o ~ ~ t g o à ~ ~ l e s o ~ ~ h o u l e c o n t\\
        r o u l e ~ ~ u s e n v e ~ ~ r l è m ~ ~ l e i l ~ ~ r e l a j e t é e\\
        l e n t e ~ ~ r r a s u r ~ ~ e o m o ~ ~ a l e n ~ ~ s a n s j a m a i\\
        h o u l e ~ ~ P l u t o n ~ ~ s t e t ~ ~ t o u r ~ ~ s s a r r e t e r\\
        p a s s e ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~\\
        e t m o i l e s n é o n s m e c l i g n e n t d e l o e i l l e s m o t\\
        s s o n t e n v i t r i n e p o u r d é c h i f f r e r l a v i l l e t\\
        o u t e s l e s i m a g e s s a n i m e n t e t v o i l a q u e j e p r\\
        e n d s p a r l a m a i n l a p o é s i e q u i c o u r t l e s r u e s
    }
}


\begin{newpoem}{A Fairy Song }  % floating A Fairy Song
    Over hill, over dale,\\
    Thorough bush, thorough brier,\\
    Over park, over pale,\\
    Thorough flood, thorough fire!\\
    I do wander everywhere,\\
    Swifter than the moon's sphere;\\
    And I serve the Fairy Queen,\\
    To dew her orbs upon the green;\\
    The cowslips tall her pensioners be;\\
    In their gold coats spots you see;\\
    Those be rubies, fairy favours;\\
    In those freckles live their savours;\\
    I must go seek some dewdrops here,\\
    And hang a pearl in every cowslip's ear.    
\end{newpoem}

\poemtitle{Bar}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Fourth section}

\poemtitle{Baz}
\lipsum[2]  
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I’ll try it, but I can alredy say that yes, I whant to make a kind of “floating subsection”.